# Get SQL creation statement for statistic

Tags: sql-server

I added clustered index to my table. The statistic was created. Now how can I get the SQL statement for the statistic creation (like for instance I can do for stored procedure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a link but should do the trick...
[create script for statistics](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/30/sql-server-how-to-script-statistics-from-ssms-scripting-statistics-is-disabled-in-ssms/)